# SIm900 cannot access new simcard

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sim900

I am trying to get my sim900 to work with a new simcard, unfortunately the Orange provider denies my entry after I give sim900 the pin of the sim:

```
AT+CMEE=2
Successful response for AT query..
+CREG: 0
+CREG: 2
+CREG: 1
+CPIN: NOT READY
+CREG: 3
```

`+CREG:` 3 means I get denied.

**OK, BUT:**

- I have added a prepaid number from same carrier(Orange), and worked fine, so sim900 seems ok.
- I have tried a subscribed Orange number(my personal number, not a prepaid) in sim900 and it works perfectly.
- I have tried the new simcard with PIN, without PIN, called Orange to create a profile on this new SIM, still densest work.
- I have updated the SIM900 to 1137B15SIM900M64_ST, still densest work.
- I have started the new simcard from an Samsung S6 phone and worked fine, internet+voice+sms, the new simcard work perfectly on my phone, I added on my phone maybe it needed something...but no, when swithed to sim900, did not worked.

**I got 2 possible solutions on this, found on Internet:**

- Either the new simcard need a different Voltage.
  But i find this unlikable since, sim900 finds the new simcard and ask me the PIN. According to wiki, modern SIM cards should support 5v, 3.3v and 1.8v (ISO/IEC 7816-3 classes A, B and C, respectively).
- New simcards have only 3G "folder" saved on them, not 2G folder: [INFO HERE](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-3G-SIM-cards-and-GSM-SIM-cards-Are-these-same-or-different-things), and since my sim900 it`s a 2G, and my new simcard possible doesnt have 2G folder data on it, it may not work/register on Orange.

**Questions:**

- Can I copy 2G data from my old simcard to my new simcard? I know I can buy a smart simcard reader and just play with it.
- Would you recommend this?
- What do you think I should try?

Answer (score 0):

> New simcards have only 3G "folder" saved on them, not 2G folder:

This seems to be the issue. SIM900 will only work with 2G SIM Card.

> I have started the new simcard from an Samsung S6 phone and worked fine

As your S6 can work on 3G. You can confirm this by selecting 2G only network on your S6 and see if the sim card still registers. You can do so as shown in the links below

http://deviceguides.vodafone.ie/web/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge-plus/basic-use/network/select-network-mode

https://devicesupport.swisscom.ch/samsung/galaxy-s6/connectivity/how-to-select-network-mode/

> Can I copy 2G data from my old simcard to my new simcard? I know I can buy a smart simcard reader and just play with it.

..

> What do you think I should try?

..

> Would you recommend this?

I fear it won't work this way. You can try to get a 2G sim card from your provider, provided they have not discontinued providing such sim cards.

Your best option would be to look for an new 2G enabled sim card or try get one that has 2G enabled

Comment: Hi, than why the new 3g simcard, works if I limit my S6 phone to 2g network?